# Open problems in sub-Riemannian geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections, curvature, open-problems, sub-riemannian-geometry

What are some open problems in [sub-Riemannian geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Riemannian_geometry)?

I am interested especially in problems concerning connections and curvature, but any contribution is welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

Chapter 10 of "A Tour of Subriemannian Geometries, Their Geodesics and Applications" describes four open problems.

Comment: The AMS link for the book: http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=SURV-91-S

Answer (score 5):

Finding subriemannian geodesics of homogeneous spaces is one problem of practical importance. See http://hrl.harvard.edu/publications/khaneja02sub-riemannian.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Andrei Agrachev recently posted an article on the arXiv:  http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2590 entitled "Some open problems" that you might find interesting.  He discusses several  open problems in control theory and sub-Riemannian geometry that are of considerable interest.